# Add lines inside a table in html

Tags: css, html, razor, html-table

I have an asp.net MVC4 application which I have this table in the view `Projet` :

```
<table style="line-height:30px; ">
    <tr>
        <th style="width:20%;color:blue">
            Description de projet
        </th>
        <th style="width:20%;color:blue">
            Le client
        </th>
        <th style="width:20%;color:blue">
            Le statut du client
        </th>
        <th style="width:20%;color:blue">
            Le groupe responsable
        </th>

    </tr>

@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i += 4) {
    <tr>
        <td style="width:20%">
            <center>@Model[i]</center>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20%">
            <center>@Model[i+1]</center>
        </td>
        <td style="width:20%">
            <center>@Model[i+2]</center>
        </td>
         <td style="width:20%">
            <center>@Model[i+3]</center>
        </td>

    </tr>
}

</table>
```

My problem is: the lines inside the table is not displayed even I used the tag `<th>`.

Why this happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: What lines? Do you mean the borders? [`line-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) possibly isn't what you think it is. Also [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) is deprecated, just apply `text-align: center;` to your `td`/`th` CSS.

Comment: yes i mean the border, for a `line-height` i used it to define the space between rows

Comment: Check your css, you might have hidden the table lines (border). As David said line-height isn't for lines.

Comment: Using inline styles adds a lot of bloat to your document.  Consider using an external style sheet instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying border you can use:-

```
<table style="border: 1px solid black;">
```

Comment: it is ok for the horizontal lines, but for the vertical lines what can i add?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write like

```
<table border="1">
```

for displaying borders and lines, both horizontal and vertical.